# MySQL Multiple table joins with four tables (Race and Results tables)

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to make a MySQl query to get data from multiple tables in a database, and i have been trying but can't seem to get it right. Below is a example of my tables and what i would like.

The Database Tables Are:

```
+-------------------+  
|        Car        |  
+-------------------+  
| Car_ID (Int)      |   
| Car_Name (String) |  
+-------------------+
```

Example of Car:

```
Car_ID: 1  
Car_Name: BMW M3  

+-------------------+  
|       Race        |  
+-------------------+  
| Race_ID (Int)     |  
| Race_Car1 (Int)   |  
| Race_Car2 (Int)   |  
| Race_Number (Int) |  
+-------------------+
```

Example of Race:

```
Race_ID: 11  
Race_Car1: 3  
Race_Car2: 2  
Race_Number: 6  

+-------------------+  
|      Result       |  
+-------------------+  
| Result_ID (Int)   |   
| Result_Number (Int)|  
| Result_Result (Int)|  
+-------------------+
```

Example of Result:

```
Result_ID: 1  
Result_Number: 6  
Result_Result: 2

+-------------------+  
|    ResultType     |  
+-------------------+  
| ResultType_ID (Int)|   
| ResultType_Name (String)|  
+-------------------+
```

Example of ResultType:

```
ResultType_ID: 1  
ResultType_Name: Car1 Win
```

I would like the query that will join the Car table to the Race tables Race_Car1 and Race_Car2 fields and then the result from the Result table Result_Number must be joined with the Race_Number field and also the Result_Type must be joined into the Result_Result field.

Basically i want a result like this:

```
Race_Car1 Race_Car2 Result_Result Race_Number  
BMW M3 | Ford Focus RS | Car1 Win | 6
```

Comment: show your code  please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use  a self join for join the car moltiple time

in my answer  i show the winner car name instead of car1 or car2

```
  select a.car_name  car_1, b.car_name car_2, c.car_name winner, d.race_nymber
  from  race d
  inner join car a on a.car_ID = d.race_car_1
  inner join car b on b.car_ID = d.race_car_2
  inner join result t on t.Result_Number = d.Result_Number
  inner join car c on c.car_ID = t.Result_Result
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was exactly what i was looking for.